# Mysql Query needs clarification

Tags: mysql, database

Please i need solution for this, i wrote a query

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE (field_id  = 87 and value in ("xxxx")) AND (field_id = 88 and value in ("R,A"))
```

this results empty rows, how to write this query i want to match id and value using "AND" condition,

**My Table:**

[image]

Solution gave was:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING
    SUM((field_id, value) = (87, 'xxxx')) > 0 AND
    SUM((field_id, value) = (88, 'R')) > 0;
```

though it uses assertion and it doesn't fetch for "in" condition like value in ("R","A")

please help, it should match `field_id = 87` and value in `('R','A')` like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your query as:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM test
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING
    SUM((field_id, value) = (87, 'xxxx')) > 0 AND
    SUM((field_id, value) = (88, 'R')) > 0 AND
    SUM((field_id, value) = (88, 'A')) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE (field_id = 87 and value in ("xxxx")) OR (field_id = 88 and value in ("R", "A"))`

Please note `OR` instead of `AND`, and quotes in `value in ("R", "A")`.

`OR` because you're checking each row against a condition and one row cannot have both field_ids.

Quotes because you quote each value, not the values list.